# XCTest UITests fails at app launch with Expired token error

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

I am unable to run UI tests for a few days. It is failing while app launch portion with error

> Expired token: no operation still exists for this token`.

If i run the whole class which contains more tests, most of them will fail for the same reason.

Has anyone else had this problem? And, more important, found a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue , any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in code signing options for the test bundle itself.

When you enable "Automatically manage signing" checkbox within "Signing & Capabilities" tab of target settings in Xcode 11, it will modify your project settings by adding the following keys:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "-";
CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = "";
```

My solution was to remove all custom keys except:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = Mac Developer
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = <Your team identifier>
```

Here's more visual instruction:
[image: Code signing settings for UI Tests target]

After that, I was able to run my UI Test for my Mac app.